# Unable to grab UITableViewCell to move it (reorder) because of subView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I was being able to move my tableViewCells just fine until I added a UIView as subView of my UITableViewCell. The width of this subView is the same of my cell. This means it covers it completely. This subView is in fact transparent enough for the grabber control to be seen even though it is over it.

I understand I am not being able to move the cells to reorder them because the view that I put over my tableViewCell is covering it completely and is over the grabber control and is not letting the grabber control detect the pan gesture.

Is it possible somehow for my views to detect this pan gesture and pass it on to the grabber control so that I can reorder the cells?
If not, is it possible to do this cell moving and reorder manually? (Having my own cell grabber control over my tableView).
Some objective C snippet will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you use reorderControls?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Why is your subview covering the whole cell? Subviews should only be added to a cell's `contentView`. Then this problem is avoided.

Comment: Thank you rmaddy! You have saved my day! Using [myCell.contentView addSubView:myView] instead of  [myCell addSubView:myView] has solved my problem!